# Checkout Git project in Android Studio causes "project does not use Gradle"

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Previously I had a project, used `Gradle` as build system and `Git` as VCS and only added `src/`, `res/`, `assets/` and `manifest.xml` to the repository. (As it is recommended I ignored all build files). Now I use `android-studio-3.1.2` and tried to import that project:

```
Checkout project from Version Control → Git → clone
```

Then selected `yes` for `Would you like to create an Android Studio project for the sources you have checked out to … ?`

```
create project from existing source → select project name, location and type (.idea) → …
```

But I ended by this warning:

```
Migrate Project to Gradle?
This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
```

What causes this problem and how I can solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is caused by ignoring `build.gradle` files (in project and it's modules) and `settings.gradle`.

Also I did not find any way to solve that automatically by Android Studio. I have to create a project from scratch and move my files to that.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need  import project from scratch!
It is gradle problem which doesnot come from git
If you have latest android project,
You can copy  paste "The Gradle" to project which have not  gradle configuration!
It is more easy